# Get number of pixels traveled in animation jQuery Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

How calculate and show the number of pixels traveled by an div element along another div (a box) since starting point(left bottom corner)  to current point (any point/moment in which user click a button) in a jQuery JavaScript animation?

```
[This is a very similar animation][1] 

[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/mykssutm/1/
```

This is the css code:

```
      #box  {

            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 500px;
            background: #ffffff;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #909090;
            -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #909090;
            box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #909090;
            margin: 20px;


            }

    .circle {

        position: relative; 
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width:50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50px; 
        background-color:#66d9ff;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #00bfff, #ccf2ff);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#00bfff), to(#ccf2ff));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #00bfff, #ccf2ff);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #00bfff, #ccf2ff);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #00bfff, #ccf2ff);
        border: 5px solid #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #909090; 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #909090; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #909090; 
        -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #909090; 
        display: none;
    }
```

HTML code:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <div id="box" class="box track-box" >
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>

        <button id="boton" class="btn btn-primary">Show traveled pixels </button>
    </div>
```

JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function() {

    var $box = $("#box");
    var $circle = $box.find(".circle").show();
    var alignment = 0;
    var easing = "swing";
    var duration =5000;
    var circleCentre = {
        x: $circle.width() / 2,
        y: $circle.height() / 2
    };
    var align = {
        x: alignment * circleCentre.x,
        y: alignment * circleCentre.y
    }
    var path = $box.rectangularPath(align);

    $circle.animateOnPath({
        startPoint: path[path.length - 1],
        path: path,
        hotspot: circleCentre,
        duration: duration,
        easing: easing
    }).promise().then(function() {
        // when the whole animation is complete
        $circle.hide();
    });


 });


 $('#boton').click(function() {

   /* calculate traveled pixels */  
 alert("Traveled pixels:" + travaledPixels);
    });   


(function($) {
   var defaults = {
    startPoint: null, // the point to which this is to be set before the   animation begins
    path: [], // an array of any number of (x,y) coordinates
    hotspot: { x: 0, y: 0 }, // the point relative to this's (left,top) that will be animated on the path.
    duration: 400, // time in milliseconds ***per leg*** of the path.
    easing: 'swing'
};
    $.fn.animateOnPath = function (opts) {
      var that = this, settings;
    // if(that.is(":animated")) return this;
    settings = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);
    if(settings.startPoint) {
        //send this to start point
        that.css({ 
left: settings.startPoint.x - settings.hotspot.x,
              top: settings.startPoint.y - settings.hotspot.y
        });
    }
     // build an .animate() chain, each step of which is one leg of the    path  of duration settings.duration.
         return settings.path.reduce(function(jq, point) {
         return jq.animate({
            left: point.x - settings.hotspot.x,
             top: point.y - settings.hotspot.y
        }, settings.duration, settings.easing);
    }, that);
}
})(jQuery);



/* 
jQ.rectangularPath()
A jQuery plugin that returns a rectangular path 
*/
(function($) {
   $.fn.rectangularPath = function(align) {
align = align || { x:0, y:0 };
      var that = this.eq(0);
      return [
        { x: that.width() + align.x, y: that.height() + align.y },
        { x: that.width() + align.x, y: -align.y },
        { x: -align.x, y: -align.y },
        { x: -align.x, y: that.height() + align.y }
        ];
    }
    })(jQuery);

    </script>
```

Comment: Show the code which you are working on, it is a good practice to add some of your attempts with the question.

Comment: I added the code @RejithRKrishnan :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution. It can calculate pixels traveled in any direction, e.g. even along a diagonal or a curve, without being limited to the horizontal and vertical directions of travel in your demo.

I'm relatively new to promises, so I can't guarantee that I've got all of the code formulated properly and/or completely, but it gives the desired results.

For reasons I couldn't yet figure out, I had to delay starting the calculation of the cumulative distance traveled until the after the first few iterations. (See the section that includes `if (numberOfSteps < 2) ...`.) Otherwise there was an initial distance of 20-some pixels that was added right at the beginning, probably due to some manipulation that moved the circle from its initial (invisible?) starting location to the bottom left corner of the rectangle.

```js
var dfd = $.Deferred();
var promise = dfd.promise();

var currTop;
var currLeft;
var prevTop;
var prevLeft;
var dist = 0;
var numberOfSteps = 0;

promise.progress(function() {
  var circlePosn = $(".circle").position();
  currTop  = circlePosn.top;
  currLeft = circlePosn.left;
  if (!prevTop ) prevTop  = currTop;
  if (!prevLeft) prevLeft = currLeft;
  var x = currLeft - prevLeft;
  var y = currTop  - prevTop;
  if (numberOfSteps < 2) {
    numberOfSteps += 1;
  } else {
    dist += Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
  }
  $("#pixelsTraveled").text("pixels traveled: " + dist);
  prevTop = currTop;
  prevLeft = currLeft;
});

$(window).load(function() {

  var $box = $("#box");
  var $circle = $box.find(".circle").show();
  var alignment = 0;
  var easing = "swing";
  var duration = 5000;
  var circleCentre = {
    x: $circle.width() / 2,
    y: $circle.height() / 2
  };
  var align = {
    x: alignment * circleCentre.x,
    y: alignment * circleCentre.y
  }
  var path = $box.rectangularPath(align);

  $circle.animateOnPath({
    startPoint: path[path.length - 1],
    path: path,
    hotspot: circleCentre,
    duration: duration,
    easing: easing
  }).promise().then(function() {
    // when the whole animation is complete
    $circle.hide();
  });


});


$('#boton').click(function() {

  /* calculate traveled pixels */
  alert("Traveled pixels:" + dist);
});


(function($) {
  var defaults = {
    startPoint: null, // the point to which this is to be set before the   animation begins
    path: [], // an array of any number of (x,y) coordinates
    hotspot: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }, // the point relative to this's (left,top) that will be animated on the path.
    duration: 400, // time in milliseconds ***per leg*** of the path.
    easing: 'swing'
  };
  $.fn.animateOnPath = function(opts) {
    var that = this,
      settings;
    // if(that.is(":animated")) return this;
    settings = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);
    if (settings.startPoint) {
      //send this to start point
      that.css({
        left: settings.startPoint.x - settings.hotspot.x,
        top: settings.startPoint.y - settings.hotspot.y
      });
    }
    // build an .animate() chain, each step of which is one leg of the    path  of duration settings.duration.
    return settings.path.reduce(function(jq, point) {
      return jq.animate({
        left: point.x - settings.hotspot.x,
        top: point.y - settings.hotspot.y
      }, {
        duration: settings.duration,
        easing: settings.easing,
        progress: function(promise, progress) {
          dfd.notify(progress);
        }
      });
    }, that);
  }
})(jQuery);



/* 
jQ.rectangularPath()
A jQuery plugin that returns a rectangular path 
*/
(function($) {
  $.fn.rectangularPath = function(align) {
    align = align || {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };
    var that = this.eq(0);
    return [{
      x: that.width() + align.x,
      y: that.height() + align.y
    }, {
      x: that.width() + align.x,
      y: -align.y
    }, {
      x: -align.x,
      y: -align.y
    }, {
      x: -align.x,
      y: that.height() + align.y
    }];
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#box {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #909090;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #909090;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #909090;
  margin: 20px;
}
.circle {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #66d9ff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #00bfff, #ccf2ff);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#00bfff), to(#ccf2ff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #00bfff, #ccf2ff);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #00bfff, #ccf2ff);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #00bfff, #ccf2ff);
  border: 5px solid #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #909090;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #909090;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #909090;
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #909090;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pixelsTraveled"></div>
<div id="notes"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
  <h2>Column 1</h2>
  <div id="box" class="box track-box">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>

  <button id="boton" class="btn btn-primary">Show traveled pixels</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew Willems your answer works perfect. I'm new in the front-end world so i was very confused.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. For being "new", you had a pretty nice jQuery animation.